# Redirecting non-WWW and HTTP to HTTPS://WWW... in only one step?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

let's say my site has both HTTPS and WWW in the url, as opposed to http mysite.com.

The way I have my .htaccess setup, if someone enters http mysite.com the path will be the following: redirection to https, THEN redirection to www.

My .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
ServerSignature Off
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.mysite.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*) http: (cant write url here) mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc,l]
</IfModule>
```

NOTE: I haven't implemented https yet, I'm just figuring out how to do it.

I know there is another thread about this but I can't really understand how to do this as my htaccess looks different.

Can I make this into one step? I'm worried several 301s would diminish the value of a link in the eyes of Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use this rule to Redirect to `https://www` in a single http request

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```